# React state not updating after fetch .then statement

Tags: reactjs, state

So I am trying to make an API request and then save the response into state.

```
await fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => setSearchResponse(data))
.then(console.log("api request fired."))
.then(console.log(searchResponse.results))
```

When I console.log the state, it still comes up as an empty object. If I run the code a second time it works as intended. The state seems to not be updating before the console.log is called but it's my understanding that this is asynchronous code and each .then line doesn't fire until the previous line is complete?

Chrome console:

[image]

**EDIT**: ADDING MORE CODE FOR CLARITY

```
function App() {
const [searchResponse, setSearchResponse] = useState("");
const [secondarySearchResponse, setsecondarySearchResponse] = useState();
const [information, setInformation] = useState();
const [secondaryInformation, setSecondaryInformation] =    useState(null);
const [dataReady, setDataReady] = useState(false);
const pos = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  pos.current = position;
  console.log(pos.current);
});
}, []);

const key = "";
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
var place_id;

async function fetchInfo() {

const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${pos.current.coords.latitude},${pos.current.coords.longitude}&radius=12000&type=restaurant&key=${key}`;

await fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => setSearchResponse(data))
  .then(console.log("api request fired."))
  .then(console.log(searchResponse))
}
```

I am calling this function with a button onClick:

```
<Button variant="primary" onClick={fetchInfo}>
   Spin
 </Button>{" "}
```

Comment: @Matt Oestreich I've added more code for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just continue the promise chain for the fetch call with redundant code and expect the state to reflect properly.

State is asynchronously updated (or rather the state update engages an asynchronous process). So just because the fetch promise chain moves to the next `.then`, doesn't mean react is finished with the state update process.

Let's say this bit of code is in your `useEffect` life cycle method:

```
await fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => setSearchResponse(data))
```

You could then utilize the `searchResponse` state data in your component within the render method inside your jsx. This is because jsx is updated every time state changes occur, therefore state updates will be reflected here.

There are other ways to view state updates in your code. The important concept here is to understand why you *can't* in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. So my promise chain is moving before the state is actually updated.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @c0lton If this was a proper solution for you, please consider accepting as the answer to your question. Thanks!